# Flutter | listen to IPC channel

Tags: flutter, dart, ipc

Im using Flutter desktop I'm trying to communicate with other applications on the device.
I tried to use IPC(inter-process communication) for that.

Is it possible to listen to an IPC channel when using a Flutter desktop?
Any other suggestion on how should I communicate between those apps